# Updating/Editing Parse Object by UITableview Cell (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a tableview that is full of current user data that is stored in parse. I want to be able to click on the cell of the parse data and be able to edit that data in a edit screen then be able to save it and it update in the parse class. I saw this code on the parse developer website regarding updating objects https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-updating-objects

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ"
                         block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error) {

gameScore[@"cheatMode"] = @YES;
gameScore[@"score"] = @1338;
[gameScore saveInBackground];
}];
```

but the problem is that in the

```
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ"
                         block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error)
```

is a query by the specific ObjectId that is stated. How do I change this so that when a user clicks on the tableview cell the query runs by that specific ObjectId in parse so I can edit the strings associated with the ObjectId. Any tutorials or guidance is really appreciated!

Here is my Tableview.m

```
@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
        // Custom the table

        // The className to query on
        self.parseClassName = @"rep";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"name";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        //self.objectsPerPage = 10;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(refreshTable:)
                                                 name:@"refreshTable"
                                               object:nil];
    {
        UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Delete Cannot Be Undone" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,  nil];
        [Alert show];
    }

}
- (void)refreshTable:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    // Reload the recipes
    [self loadObjects];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"refreshTable" object:nil];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable

{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"rep"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];



    return query;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RepCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name" ];

    UILabel *time = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
   time.text = [object objectForKey:@"time"];


    return cell;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // Remove the row from data model
    PFObject *objectToDel = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [objectToDel deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {



        UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"Item Was Deleted Successfully. Pull Down to Refresh Tab" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil,  nil];
        [Alert show];
        [self loadView];

    }
     ];
}

- (void) objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error
{
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}





@end
```

Comment: do you already have the code for the tableView?

Comment: @adolfosrs i just added it to my question! Thank you!

Comment: Where is `loadObjects` method?

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
along with the PFQuery